# SSRS 2016 issue - Web Portal URL is showing "Could not load folder contents "

Tags: ssrs

I need help for one if report server issue, We have migrated the SQL server from 2014 to 2016 using in-place upgrade. After upgradation we are having issue with web portal URL and it is showing "Could not load folder contents " error message while opening the url. We have already applied Service pack 2 on the SQL instance. Can someone help on this? Anyone faced such scenario. Please help

[image]

Comment: Probably this could be issue of encryption keys. open report server configuration manager and delete encryption keys and restart reporting services. I hope it would solve issue. note:try to take report sererver db and encryption key backup to do any changes.

Comment: I have already tried this but no luck. thanks for checking this.